# Why my program in which a child process is forked needs user to type 'Enter' before exiting?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, posix

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int p[2];
    char *argv[2];
    argv[0] = "wc";
    argv[1] = "-w";
    argv[2] = NULL;

    pipe(p);
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(0);
        dup(p[0]);
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
    }
    else
    {
        close(p[0]);
        write(p[1], "hello world\n", 12);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "hello world\n");
}
```

And when I run it:

```
$ gcc a.c
$ ./a.out
```

I got the following:

```
hello world
$ 2
_    // the cursor is flickering here
```

After I type `Enter`, the program exit. What is the reason for this? In addition, if I exchange the content in the parent process and child process like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int p[2];
    char *argv[2];
    argv[0] = "wc";
    argv[1] = "-w";
    argv[2] = NULL;

    pipe(p);
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(p[0]);
        write(p[1], "hello world\n", 12);
    }
    else
    {
        close(0);
        dup(p[0]);
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "hello world\n");
}
```

I got the output as I expect:

```
hello world
2
$
```

The program has exited and is ready to get next command. What's the problem of the first program?

Comment: For one thing, your `char *argv[2]` needs to be `argv[3]` to hold the two parameters you wanted **plus** the terminating NULL pointer.

Comment: The output from the background `wc` is printed after the prompt.  Your shell is waiting for you to type a command,  For example, type `ps` immediately after the `2` is printed and see what processes are running.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes that's true. The program has exited at that time. The output of `wc` comes after the prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look very carefully at your output, you'll see that your program *has* exited:

```
hello world
$ 2
_    // the cursor is flickering here
```

See how the `$` is printed? This is your shell waiting for input as usual. By pressing `enter` you've just input a blank command to your shell and obtained a second `$` prompt.

What's the `2` doing there? That's `wc`'s output. Your program isn't actually waiting for `wc` to exit. This means that your program exits *before* `wc` does, so the shell resumes, prints its prompt, and only *then* does `wc` exit and print `2`.

To fix, you'll probably want to add some kind of `wait` call to wait for the child process in the parent.